# Custom Touch Handling in Android

Tags: java, android, user-interface, touch-event

I needed access to the ACTION_UP that occurs after the ACTION_MOVE event, and the SimpleOnGestureListener didn't directly support that, so I tried to implement custom touch handling in an activity's onTouchEvent method, in order to get more familiar with it.

The activity is an alarm clock's alert screen (appears when an alarm goes off).
There are 5 kinds of gestures I need to handle. They are:

```
Single tap - Visual feedback
Double tap - Snooze the alarm
Swipe along the Y access - visual feedback based on distance swiped.
ACTION_UP after an ACTION_MOVE with a distance of less than 50% of the screen's Y axis - visual feedback.
ACTION_UP after an ACTION_MOVE with a distance of greater than 50% of the screen's Y axis - dismiss the alarm.
```

The function I wrote doesn't work correctly, and I'm pretty sure that it is because the variable "startEvent" is being set on every call to onTouchEvent, when it should be only set on the ACTION_DOWN events of a swipe or the first tap of a double tap.

Here is my code:

```
private final int DOUBLE_TAP_TIMEOUT = 500;  // ms
private boolean isScrolling = false;  // flag used to detect the ACTION_UP after a scroll
private boolean possibleDoubleTap = false;  // flag used to detect a double tap 
private MotionEvent startEvent;  // the event that starts the gesture we are trying to detect
private float yPercentScrolled;  // the percent the along the (Y axis / 2) that has been scrolled.
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){

    switch (event.getActionMasked()){

        case(MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN):
            Log.d("MOTION", "DOWN");
            // reset the startEvent given the proper conditions
            if(
                    (!isScrolling && !possibleDoubleTap) 
                    || (possibleDoubleTap && event.getEventTime() - startEvent.getEventTime() <= DOUBLE_TAP_TIMEOUT) 
            ){
                startEvent = event;
            }
            return true;

        case(MotionEvent.ACTION_UP):
            Log.d("MOTION", "UP");
            if(isScrolling){
                isScrolling = false;

                if(yPercentScrolled >= 1f){
                    dismissAlarm();
                }
                else {
                    layout.setBackgroundColor(bgColor);
                    startEvent = null;
                    possibleDoubleTap = false;
                    isScrolling = false;
                }
            }
            else if(possibleDoubleTap){
                // if we have a double tap
                if(event.getEventTime() - startEvent.getEventTime() <= DOUBLE_TAP_TIMEOUT){
                    snoozeAlarm();
                    return true;
                }
                // if we don't have a double tap, do nothing
            }
            else if(!possibleDoubleTap){
                possibleDoubleTap = true;
                layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
            }
            return true;

        case(MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE):
            Log.d("MOTION", "MOVE");
            if(!isScrolling){
                isScrolling = true;
            }
            else {
                yPercentScrolled = handleScroll(event, startEvent);
            }
            return true;

        default:
            Log.d("MOTION", "other:" + String.valueOf(event.getActionMasked()));
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

Any ideas on why "startEvent" is being reset when it shouldn't? There are no "MOTION:DOWN" in logcat when it is being reset, so this on is stumping me. This is also the only location where startEvent is being assigned to something other than null.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that `startEvent = event` is assigning a reference to object `event` instead of the object itself. so when the value of object `event` changed. the value of `startEvent` is also changed.

Try to take and store just the value that you need (in your case is the `X, Y, and EventTime`) instead of the whole `event` object.

Comment: I was actually just stepping through the debugger and realized that was the case. I used the code startEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(event); to clone the object so I could pass around the MotionEvent, instead of a few variables. I think my onTouchEvent is working properly now, but I haven't tested every input combination. Thanks.